# Forcing inheritance of animate-elements in SVG possible?

Tags: animation, inheritance, svg

Hi I have the following SVG file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="150" height="150" viewBox="0 0 150 150">

    <text x="10" y="100" fill="blue" fill-opacity="1">
        <tspan fill-opacity="1" >1st</tspan>
        <tspan                  >2nd</tspan>
        <animate attributeName="fill-opacity" calcMode="discrete" values="0; 1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </text>

</svg>
```

As you can see there is an `animate` element in the `text` element, which works fine. However the problem lies in the `tspan` elements. One of those defines no `fill-opacity` (the attribute that is changed by the animation) and inherits the animation. The other one defines its own `fill-opacity` which doesn't get changed by the animation.

Is there a way to tell the `animate` element that it should affect all child elements regardless of whether they define their own value for the changed attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. fill-opacity is a CSS property and therefore [CSS specificity](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/understanding_c) applies. The more specific child rule will always apply. You could give the tspan it's own animation of course.

Comment: I know that I could give the tspan its own animation, but wanted to avoid this. The subelement hierarchy could become quite big in the real SVG and giving each subelement its own `animate` element doesn't look like a good idea to me. 
Well, I must see, how I can cope with this.
Thanks to you.